# Attractive fonts for a title of an article aimed at physics students

Tags: fonts, formatting, titles

I am quite a newby at Tex and would like a simple, font type which would ideally attract students in reading my article which will be printed in a scientific journal. It needs to be informal. So none of the usual fonts like sans serif apply. Do you guys have any ideas of what I can do instead?

Comment: If the article is in a journal, isn't the font (and layout, etc.) controlled by the editors and not the author?

Comment: The question is not really on topic, and the answers would be opinion-based; but Merriweather, which is available in the TeXLive distribution, is a fairly bold-looking serif font that has a relatively casual feel, at least to me. It still looks professional but is a little less "square" than, say, Computer Modern.